# alert javascript not working in if cycle

Tags: javascript, html

my js file

```
function myFunction() {

var component = (document.getElementById("component").value);

var author = (document.getElementById("author").value);

var version = (document.getElementById("version").value);

var changelog = (document.getElementById("changelog").value);

if (component == "" || author == "" || version == "" || changelog == "") {

alert("Please Fill All Fields");

} else {

    alert("submission Completed");

}}
```

my HTML file

```
<form>

      <h2>Insert Component:</h2>

      <input id="component" type = "text" placeholder = "New Component">

      <h2>Author:</h2>

      <input id="author" type = "text" placeholder = "Author Name">  

      <h2>Version:</h2>

      <input id="version" type = "text" placeholder = "New Version">

      <h2>Changelog:</h2>

      <input id="changelog" type = "text" placeholder = "">
      <br>
      <br>
      <h1><input style="width:100px;height:30px;font-size: 20" name="submit" type = "button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit"></h1>

      </form>
```

also if i complete all the form fields the second alert is not shown, always the first is shown...someone can help me ? I really can't understand

Comment: your Ids in your js code are wrong - ids are case sensitive. Your html shows ids as lowercase but you're searching for them with the first letter as capital letter

Comment: FYI you can omit the parentheses surrounding each `document.getElementById("XXX").value`.

Comment: sorry i posted an old version. It doesn't work with ids in lowercase either

Comment: @AlessandroMecchia, please check http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JWKyjX   , after using correct ids, it works

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because in the code:

```
<input id="component" type = "text" placeholder = "New Component">
```

the id is **component**

and in the code you are using:
**Component**
Notice the capital **C**.
And the same goes for all elements.
So you are actually never going into the if statement

**Update**:

You also need to remove all () from the code:

```
(document.getElementById("component").value);
```

and convert them to :

```
document.getElementById("component").value;
```

```html
<script>
function myFunction() {

var component = document.getElementById("component").value;

var author = document.getElementById("author").value;

var version = document.getElementById("version").value;

var changelog = document.getElementById("changelog").value;

if (component == "" || author == "" || version == "" || changelog == "") {

alert("Please Fill All Fields");

} else {

    alert("submission Completed");

}}
</script>

<form>

      <h2>Insert Component:</h2>

      <input id="component" type = "text" placeholder = "New Component">

      <h2>Author:</h2>

      <input id="author" type = "text" placeholder = "Author Name">  

      <h2>Version:</h2>

      <input id="version" type = "text" placeholder = "New Version">

      <h2>Changelog:</h2>

      <input id="changelog" type = "text" placeholder = "">
      <br>
      <br>
      <h1><input style="width:100px;height:30px;font-size: 20" name="submit" type = "button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit"></h1>

      </form>
```

Comment: yes @JimishFotariya , even i am trying to know, it would be good, if someone leave comment for downvote..downvote for me as well :(

Answer (score 1):

**Your code is working fine but still some observations :**

- No need to use **`(`** & **`)`** while getting the input values.
- Instead of using `==` you can use `!` while comparing for no value.

Use `if (!component || !author || !version || !changelog) { ... }` instead of `if (component == "" || author == "" || version == "" || changelog == "") { ... }`

**DEMO**

```js
function myFunction() {
var component = document.getElementById("component").value;

var author = document.getElementById("author").value;

var version = document.getElementById("version").value;

var changelog = document.getElementById("changelog").value;

if (!component || !author || !version || !changelog) {

alert("Please Fill All Fields");

} else {

    alert("submission Completed");

}
};
```

```html
<form>

      <h2>Insert Component:</h2>

      <input id="component" type = "text" placeholder = "New Component">

      <h2>Author:</h2>

      <input id="author" type = "text" placeholder = "Author Name">  

      <h2>Version:</h2>

      <input id="version" type = "text" placeholder = "New Version">

      <h2>Changelog:</h2>

      <input id="changelog" type = "text" placeholder = "">
      <h1><input style="width:100px;height:30px;font-size: 20" name="submit" type = "button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit"></h1>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use correct ids-(component,author,version,changelog) to achieve expected result

```
var component = (document.getElementById("component").value);

var author = (document.getElementById("author").value);

var version = (document.getElementById("version").value);

var changelog = (document.getElementById("changelog").value);
```

Codepen - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JWKyjX for referece

Both alerts will work after correct ids

Issue:

Value of fields is always empty due to incorrect id values, hence you are getting only first alert everytime.